# Be use or be used?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which one is correct and please explain it

1. It can be use
2. It can be used (by someone)

Second one is passive I know that but is the number 1 is also correct way to say?.

Comment: #1 is *never* syntactically valid. #2 *could* be a "passive verb" usage meaning *somebody [unspecified] **would be able to use it***, but it could also be a "past tense verb form used as an adjective*. As in *I'm definitely buying a car - a new one if I can afford it, but if not it can be used* (*used = **second-hand, pre-owned***).

Comment: *It can be **of** use* (it's ***useful***). Same syntax as *This thing is **of** value (**valuable**), That thing is **of** no interest (**uninteresting**).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Must you always give answers in comments? They are not easy to read in relation to questions asked, very often.

Answer (score 1):

There is **"to be *of* use"** (= to be useful), but no "to be use".

For example, here is a quote from a speaker at Harvard:

> “I chose medicine, not because I was scientifically-minded, for I was deeply ignorant of science. I chose it because as a doctor, I could go anywhere I pleased—to far off lands or city slums—and be quite sure I could **be of use** anywhere.”
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/features/convocation-2019-dean-williams/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is not correct.

You can say "It can be used." meaning "Someone can use it".  You can also use the noun "use" (/ju:s/, not /ju:z/).  "It is of use", meaning "It has a purpose". Similarly you might ask "Is this any use?" Finally, you can say, for example, "Hunting is a use of a gun"

There is also an adjective "used" (/ju:zd/) so you can say "It is used", if you are talking about a used car, for example.